# Set GitHub secret keys in bulk – sh file

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I’m in the initial stages of building a simple automated deploy pipeline. One of the steps I’d like to implement would be setting the GitHub Actions secrets in bulk, since I have many of them in my project.
Note: I’m a newbie in DevOps and bash scripts.

- Terminal: I’m using git bash;
- OS: I’m using windows 10, however, I’d like for the same script to work in windows and linux/unix terminals;

Up till now, this is what I’ve got:

```bash
REPO_OWNER="your-username"
REPO_NAME="your-repo"
GITHUB_TOKEN="your-personal-access-token"

# Function to get the latest public key.
get_public_key() {
  local response
  response=$(curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_OWNER/$REPO_NAME/actions/secrets/public-key")
  echo "$response" | jq -r '.key,.key_id'
}

# Associative array of secrets and their values.
declare -A secrets
secrets["SECRET1_TEST"]="value1"
secrets["SECRET2_TEST "]="value2"
secrets["SECRET3_TEST "]="value3"

# Get the latest public key
public_key_info=($(get_public_key))
public_key="${public_key_info[0]}"
key_id="${public_key_info[1]}"

for secret in "${!secrets[@]}"; do
  # Get the secret value from the associative array.
  secret_value="${secrets[$secret]}"

  # Encrypt the secret using the public key
  encrypted_value=$(echo -n "$secret_value" | openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey <(echo "$public_key") | openssl enc -base64 -A)

  # Set the secret using the GitHub API.
  curl -X PUT \
    -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_OWNER/$REPO_NAME/actions/secrets/$secret" \
    -d "{\"encrypted_value\":\"$encrypted_value\",\"key_id\":\"$key_id\"}"
done
```

When running this script, I get the following error:

```
Could not open file or uri for loading public key from /proc/1885/fd/63: No such file or directory
pkeyutl: Error initializing context
{
  "message": "Invalid request.\n\n does not match /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\\/]{4})$/.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/secrets#create-or-update-a-repository-secret"        
}
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong with the script? Or any other approach suggestion?

**Edit: Debug**
I’m debugging the script. Seems that `encrypted_value` is printing empty.

Comment: Looks like things go wrong when trying to feed the `openssl` command with non-good values? A good way to start debugging is to stuff `set -x` at the top of your script to enable bash "debug mode" and see values of all your variables. And you should _always_ use `set -e` to make scripts exit at the first error that occurs, and not try to execute the rest of the script regardless. You can combine them: `set -xe`.